# Restore a deleted Note - no Deleted Notes folder?

Tags: iphone, notes.app

I put my phone in my pocket unlocked and when I took it out again it had opened Notes, deleted my growing task list and made a new empty note.

I opened Notes on my Mac, and saw the note in question, yay! ...and then sync kicked in and deleted it.

Guides suggest looking in the Deleted Notes folder, but I don't have one of those on any of my platforms.

Can anyone offer a reason this might be happening?

Comment: Try Time Machine in`~/Library/Group Containers/group.com.apple.notes/` [I've never seen a deleted notes folder.]

Answer (score 0):

On Big Sur there is a folder called "Recently Deleted", however there seems to be a bug where the folder sometimes does not show on a device that has not deleted a note.

Either look for the folder on your iPhone or on your Mac: Create a new note and delete it, see if that triggers the folder to show up.

Comment: It did make it appear - but the original missing note is not in it. I also had the original note pinned to my opening screen, which now states "Note No Longer Available". Looks like its gone for good.

Comment: I guess a last resort could be to check if it's still available on the web (icloud.com).

Comment: Tried that. When I logged in it was there, but it literally disappeared as I watched.

Comment: If TimeMachine is enabled on your Mac you could try the answers provided on this question: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/229357/recover-notes-from-timemachine